# How to hide or unhide app in MIUI drawer?

Tags: applications, miui, app-drawer

In MIUI I have Files app hidden. I don't have it in my drawer. I can run it by adb shell like this:

```
am start -n com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.LauncherActivity
```

But how do I add this activity to drawer? I was trying [THIS](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/documentsui) way, but I cant find this piece of xml in sysconfig. Maybe because I have android 9.

Also, I don't know if I'm supposed to create new topic about this, but is there any option on sources.android.com to see previous versions of the page (It could help me to figure out how to show it in andro 9)?

**EDIT:**

*In Android 10, the DocumentsUI module uses is_launcher_enabled to determine if the Files launcher icon should display in the app drawer.*

I extracted the apk file with the ApkExtractor and checked this flag with the APK Editor Studio. I don't know if it gave me files actually used by the app, but It seems to be untouched:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:enabled="@bool/is_launcher_enabled">
```

**res/values/bool.xml**

```
<bool name="is_launcher_enabled">true</bool>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Re: *see previous versions of the page*, Android doesn't provide such functionality, so you have to use 3rd-party services like [Internet Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).