# How to install an app from unknown source when the phone is protected by Family Link?

Tags: redmi, android-13

Due to [some essential system component missing in my Android 13 / Redmi 11S](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253267/20449) I have to install customized version of my app. I need to execute .apk file from Downloads folder.

The thing is that this phone is protected by Google Family Link.

When I try to uninstall the app, an information box appears telling me that this operation has been blocked by the system administrator. When I went ot corresponding section of the settings, I can clearly see that removing such system administrator is impossible.

What to do in this case?

Comment: I never used family link,, but [this](https://support.bark.us/hc/en-us/articles/360050416571-Install-or-Update-Bark-on-Androids-Supervised-with-Family-Link) may help //If it works please make it into an answer yourself!

Comment: From Google support site: https://support.google.com/families/answer/9204736

Comment: @MorrisonChang I believe that the information provided under this link won't help, because it says about accessing account data only. It seems it doesn't say anything about device administrator apps (which are the key in this question).

Comment: @beeshyams From a very quick take-a-look it seems that solution provided under your shared link should work. I'll double check in the evening and do as you suggest, if you truly works. Thanks.