# How to unhide Phone and Messaging apps

Tags: sms, custom-roms, hardware

I have an embedded device running Android and using SIM card for data connectivity. For whatever reason, the Phone and Messaging apps are hidden. I can see them in the System Apps list and Messaging app will appear if I send an SMS to the number that is associated with the SIM that is inserted into the device. Is there a way to actually show the Phone and Messaging apps in the apps list? The main reason is so I can use the Phone app to top-up my account to ensure that the data package is always current.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Since the apps can be accessed even if hidden, then they don't seem to be disabled/"uninstalled". Thus, could you install a 3rd-party launcher app (or any 3rd-party app from the Play Store/using APK)? This is based on my knowledge since we have had a similar requirement to hide some apps from the UI by developing a custom launcher app that filters out apps based on their package name.

Comment: Or use an activity launcher to create short cut to the app(s) // See. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/253276/131553

Comment: [How to see package names](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name), just in case you need